Quantum Dimer Model with Multiple Chemical Potentials
Regarding the commonly known quantum dimer model on the honeycomb lattice

See References: Phys. Rev. B 64, 144416 and Phys. Rev. B 69, 224415
only a chemical potential $v$ for the one possible type of configuration on the hexagon is considered (the resonating one).
I wonder if the ground-state phase diagram of the quantum dimer model changes qualitatively if further chemical potentials are introduced for other configurations of dimers on the hexagon?
For the sake of simplicity I would assume that the chemical potential for the relevant resonating configuration still has the largest amplitude.
Are there references studying such generalized quantum dimer models?
